# Spring Cloud Gateway can't deal with Post request with parameter which has "==", how to deal with this?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using spring cloud gateway as API gateway in my spring cloud project

I find that if a post reqeust is with parameter which has "==", then the response will have the following warning:

```
 "error": "Internal Server Error",

    "message": "Invalid character '=' for QUERY_PARAM in \"%7B%22businessType%22:%22ftTranslate%22,%22command%22:%22sentence%22,%22data%22:%20%7B%22origin%22:%22zh%22,%22target%22:%22en%22,%22udid%22:%22%22%7D,%22tcl%22:%20%7B%22clientId%22:%221a5bf636-34ca-4aec-8bca-08d2a276ada1%22,%22subSysId%22:9,%22token%22:%22ua_73g+Qkl/nSMb7oPiqiwofOxrWnVp9zXWqMZ2FNT0Yam6Fv5zbQioS3I9+ws7WBPHGF/aVHHpMeC/g7L7BM/xWX/ghCZRLlzwmvDPA7SZnDUlbLOzGyxaXg==%22%7D,%22version%22:%221.0.0%22%7D\""
```

server log

��java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  Invalid  character  '='  for  QUERY_PARAM  in  "%7B%22businessType%22:%22ftTranslate%22,%22command%22:%22sentence%22,%22data%22:%20%7B%22origin%22:%22zh%22,%22target%22:%22en%22,%22udid%22:%22%22%7D,%22tcl%22:%20%7B%22clientId%22:%221a5bf636-34ca-4aec-8bca-08d2a276ada1%22,%22subSysId%22:9,%22token%22:%22ua_73g+Qkl/nSMb7oPiqiwofOxrWnVp9zXWqMZ2FNT0Yam6Fv5zbQioS3I9+ws7WBPHGF/aVHHpMeC/g7L7BM/xWX/ghCZRLlzwmvDPA7SZnDUlbLOzGyxaXg==%22,%22source%22:%22app%22%7D,%22version%22:%221.0.0%22%7D" at  org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.verifyUriComponent(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:333)  ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at  org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.lambda$verify$2(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:301)  ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at  java.util.Map.forEach(Map.java:630)  ~[na:1.8.0_191] at  org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.verify(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:298)  ~[spri ng-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.build(UriComponentsBuilder.java:345) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter.filter(RouteToRequestUrlFilter.java:73) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler$GatewayFilterAdapter.filter(FilteringWebHandler.java:133) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.OrderedGatewayFilter.filter(OrderedGatewayFilter.java:44) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler$DefaultGatewayFilterChain.lambda$filter$0(FilteringWebHandler.java:115) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:45) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:271) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:803) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1083) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.drain(FluxFilterWhen.java:262) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterWhen.java:131) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.DrainUtils.postCompleteDrainDelayError(DrainUtils.java:296) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.DrainUtils.postCompleteDelayError(DrainUtils.java:357) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDematerialize$DematerializeSubscriber.onComplete(FluxDematerialize.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDematerialize$DematerializeSubscriber.onNext(FluxDematerialize.java:102) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDematerialize$DematerializeSubscriber.onNext(FluxDematerialize.java:42) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drainAsync(FluxFlattenIterable.java:391) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.pu

how to deal with this? thanks

Comment: Are there any logs on the server?